# Spring Data Hadoop

Tags: spring, spring-data-hadoop

I using Hadoop 2.4.x, Spring 4.0.6, Spring-Data-Hadoop 2.0.1.RELEASE-hadoop24

I'm running only jar file then no problems. But Running with tomcat have some error;

**my hadoop config is below:**

```
<hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
   fs.default.name=hdfs://xxxx:9000
</hdp:configuration>
```

And Running Tomcat 7.0.52 version.

**And now the error**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hadoopConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/google/common/collect/Interners, method: newWeakInterner signature: ()Lcom/google/common/collect/Interner;) Incompatible argument to function
>        at

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace? Probably a version conflict for the Google Guava libraries. Could you look to see what Guava versions are on your classpath?

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace?

Comment: If you use maven. Could you provide output for next command?
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.guava

Comment: Did you solve this issue??